# Python: Keras: How to convert a simple list to np array for machine learning model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a list `l1 = ["Hello", "What is your name", "How ya Doing?"]`
and `l2 = ["Hi", "I am XYZ", "I'm fine, What about you"]`

I want to train my model according to the index of their lists.

> Problem: It requires np array for training. How to convert this list
> l1 and l2 to a np array that keras would accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy has a function to convert a python list to an array. All you need is

```
import numpy as np  

l1 = ["Hello", "What is your name", "How ya Doing?"]
l2 = ["Hi", "I am XYZ", "I'm fine, What about you"]

arr1 = np.array(l1)
arr2 = np.array(l2)
print(arr1,arr2[1])
```

returns

```
['Hello' 'What is your name' 'How ya Doing?'] 'I am XYZ'
```

which should do the job.